# getting ImportError when import 'highspy'

Tags: solver, pulp

I am trying to solve an optimization problem through Pulp by different solvers.
to use 'HiGHS_CMD', installed 'highspy' package by pip and it was successfully installed.
But when I try to import it, it returns back the ImportError.
I would appreciate it if you suggest to me any effective wat to solve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrUVL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgApv.png)

I installed different versions of Pulp but the problem is still there.